# How can I close the current window and open a new window at the same time?

Tags: python, tkinter

This code opens a menu, which links to another menu. The first button can't close itself and open a new one at the same time, How do I fix this?

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as box


class EnterRLE(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Enter RLE')
        self.line_count_str = tk.StringVar()
        self.compressed_data_str = tk.StringVar(self)

        frame = tk.Frame(self)

        tk.Label(self, text='Line Count:').pack(padx=15, pady=5)
        tk.Entry(self, bd=5, textvariable=self.line_count_str).pack(padx=15, pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Next", width=5, command=self.line_count_func).pack(side='right', padx=5)
        tk.Button(self, text='Exit', width=5, command=self.destroy).pack(side='right', padx=5)
        frame.pack(padx=100, pady=19)

    def line_count_func(self):
        if self.line_count_str.get().isdigit():
            if int(self.line_count_str.get()) < 3:
                box.showinfo(title="Error", message="Enter a number over 3")
            elif int(self.line_count_str.get()) > 1000000000:
                box.showinfo(title="Error", message="Enter a number under 1,000,000,000")
            else:
                self.enter_rle_2()

    def enter_rle_2(self):
        top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        top.title('Enter RLE')
        frame = tk.Frame(top)
        tk.Label(top, text='Compressed Data:').pack(padx=15, pady=5)
        tk.Entry(top, bd=5, textvariable=self.compressed_data_str).pack(padx=15, pady=5)
        tk.Button(top, text="Next").pack(side='right', padx=5)
        frame.pack(padx=19)





EnterRle1().mainloop()
```

I have seen some people use a new "def" approach for this type of thing however i'm not sure how to adapt these to my code.

Comment: Don't try to do it like this instead make use of `Toplevel` to create new windows and/or you can configure the main window to be one menu then configure the main window for the new menu and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.

The 1st major problem is the use of `Tk()` twice. In this specific instance when the code is cleaned up it works fine but generally you never want to use more than one instance of `Tk()`.

2nd major issue is how you are trying to destroy `enter_rle` in your `linecount_button_clicked` function. You cannot do this as the function does not know anything about `enter_rle` from a separate function. You need to pass it in your button command.

3rd major issue is `int(linecount_STR.get())`. This will error out if anything other than a number or an empty sting is grabbed by get. So your `else` clause will never happen as it will error before your `if/else` statement. So lets fix that with `isdigit()`.

Next even though it does not hurt anything here you want to define your global's at the top of your function.

There are some PEP8 issues here that don't hurt the code but would make it easier to read if you clean them up.

Really this should probably be built in a class so we can use class attributes and methods to manage everything.

Here is your code cleaned up let me know if you have any questions.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box


def enter_rle_1():
    enter_rle = Tk()
    linecount_STR = StringVar()
    enter_rle.title('Enter RLE')
    frame = Frame(enter_rle)
    label_linecount = Label(enter_rle, text='Linecount:')
    label_linecount.pack(padx=15, pady=5)
    linecount = Entry(enter_rle, bd=5, textvariable=linecount_STR)
    linecount.pack(padx=15, pady=5)
    ok_button = Button(enter_rle, text="Next", width=5,
                       command=lambda lc=linecount_STR: linecount_button_clicked(enter_rle, lc))
    ok_button.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)
    stop = Button(enter_rle, text='Exit', width=5, command=enter_rle.destroy)
    stop.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)
    frame.pack(padx=100, pady=19)
    enter_rle.mainloop()


def linecount_button_clicked(enter_rle, linecount_STR):
    linecount = linecount_STR.get()
    if linecount.isdigit():  # does nothing if value is not a digit.
        if int(linecount) < 3:
            box.showinfo(title="Error", message="Enter a number over 3")
        elif int(linecount) > 1000000000:
            box.showinfo(title="Error", message="Enter a number under 1,000,000,000")
        else:
            enter_rle_2(enter_rle)


def enter_rle_2(root):
    enter_rle = Toplevel(root)
    compressed_data_STR = StringVar(root)
    enter_rle.title('Enter RLE')
    frame = Frame(enter_rle)
    label_compressed_data = Label(enter_rle, text='Compressed Data:')
    label_compressed_data.pack(padx=15, pady=5)
    compressed_data = Entry(enter_rle, bd=5, textvariable=compressed_data_STR)
    compressed_data.pack(padx=15, pady=5)
    ok_button = Button(enter_rle, text="Next")
    ok_button.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)
    frame.pack(padx=100, pady=19)


enter_rle_1()
```

Here is an OOP version of your code using class attributes and methods. This is much easier to manage this kind of interaction in Tkinter and no global's will ever be needed.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as box


class EnterRle1(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Enter RLE')
        self.line_count_str = tk.StringVar()
        self.compressed_data_str = tk.StringVar(self)

        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        tk.Label(self, text='Line Count:').pack(padx=15, pady=5)
        tk.Entry(self, bd=5, textvariable=self.line_count_str).pack(padx=15, pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Next", width=5, command=self.line_count_func).pack(side='right', padx=5)
        tk.Button(self, text='Exit', width=5, command=self.destroy).pack(side='right', padx=5)
        frame.pack(padx=100, pady=19)

    def line_count_func(self):
        if self.line_count_str.get().isdigit():
            if int(self.line_count_str.get()) < 3:
                box.showinfo(title="Error", message="Enter a number over 3")
            elif int(self.line_count_str.get()) > 1000000000:
                box.showinfo(title="Error", message="Enter a number under 1,000,000,000")
            else:
                self.enter_rle_2()

    def enter_rle_2(self):
        top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        top.title('Enter RLE')
        frame = tk.Frame(top)
        tk.Label(top, text='Compressed Data:').pack(padx=15, pady=5)
        tk.Entry(top, bd=5, textvariable=self.compressed_data_str).pack(padx=15, pady=5)
        tk.Button(top, text="Next").pack(side='right', padx=5)
        frame.pack(padx=100, pady=19)


EnterRle1().mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for cleaning it all up, I am going to take an OOP approach to most of my work its just a little bit more confusing to do as a start. Going back to my original question, how could I have it so that when i clicked on the next button, the window closed and the new one opened from one button click?

Comment: @johnkirt well depends on the goal. If you want something like a login screen what you do is hid the root window and then bring up a `Toplevel()` window as the login screen and then destroy the Toplevel window and unhide the root at the same time. Or if you are just wanting the next window instead of trying to destroy one and open another you simply replace the widgets in the main window. For example you use a frame to hold your first screen of data then on button click you can delete that frame and place another with new data.